# Implementation/Integration of Email Subscription form for a Wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, implementation, wordpress-theming

I would like to get some ideas what's the best way to implement/integrate a Email Subscription Form for a wordpress theme i'm building. The form I'm referring is similar to this (www.babyyu.com) and (smashingmagazine.com).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out some of the existing plugins at http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ ? There are quite a few available that do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question here:
[Adding email subscription to Wordpress theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350470/adding-email-sucbscription-to-wordpress-theme)

Maybe between the two of us we'll be able to get a proper answer.

@jswat: Could you please elaborate on the appropriate plugins to download. Yes we know Wordpress has a lot of available plugins and we know the site to find them. But I believe a better answer would be to list the plugins that would accomplish this functionality.

Thanks