# Adding email subscription to Wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've developed my own Wordpress theme and I wanted to give users the ability to subscribe to my blog.

I have the typical Post RSS and Comment RSS options that come with Wordpress under the META section of the sidebar, but I also wanted to give my readers an option to just input their email address and press a button to "subscribe".

I know this is possible since I've seen many many blogs that use this, and if needed I can list some here. But I'm not sure if this is a plugin or a widget or what-have-you.

If you know how to implement this functionality into a Wordpress theme please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are enough [newsletter plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/newsletter) in the plugin directory. You shouldn't add such code into your theme; this is really a plugin job, and your users may choose another one than yours.

Answer (score 1):

Try this plugin:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subscribe2/

When i wanna add a new functionality to my WP sites, i always start by googling plugins. I mean if the solution already exists, that means less work for me, right? ;)

Answer (score 0):

This plugin is very useful if you are using feedburner http://feedburner.google.com/ for feeds.
This will open a popup to your visitor for subscriber 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/sc-popup-subscriber-form/

Answer (score 0):

You can try with https://wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack/ it's so helpful plugin for email subscription option on WordPress site.